# Certain text not showing on my webpage, jQuery script to blame?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a nice simple checkout form with a jquery script I got on the web and I seem to be facing a weird problem that could be due to a couple of things and I'm clueless as to how to fix this.

Maybe you can solve this... Below is my website in development:

[link removed]

If you look at the form (the light gray part that scrolls up and down), I have a list of cupcakes (around 30) that stretch all the way down the frame. My problem is that for no apparent reason the last 5 items don't show up, but if you look at the HTML everything is there.

The script I'm using is featureList : http://jqueryglobe.com/article/feature-list

Is this :

- a jQuery limitation?
- a `<li>` limitation?
- a `featureList` bug/limitation?
- multiple ids tags on html limitation?
- is it a stupid error and I've been looking at this code for too long?

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the HTML, you can see the z-index is -30

```
<td id="saveursqte_box_26">
    <div class="t" style="z-index: -30; ">Vanille-café
        <div class="r" style="z-index: -40; ">
            <div class="a" style="z-index: -50; "></div>
            <img src="777/galeries/g21_i41_2.jpg" border="0">
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

and the `<td>` below it has a z-index of -60.

I'm having a looking into the JS to see if I can work out where the z-indexes are being changed, maybe you know?

Comment: holy macaroni. I would never have found that. There is a script that read all tags and give them specific z-index because I had various bugs with IE and the only way i found how to fix this was that script. I just found the script had a "memory" limit of 1000... and when changing it it fixes the bug. MANY thanks. The kind of thing you can waste hoursssss looking around!

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  var zIndexNumber = 10000;
  $('div').each(function() {
  $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
  zIndexNumber -= 10;
  });
 });
</script>`

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that! I just found the same code as you posted. Completely missed it the first time I read through.

Comment: Actually no it can't, it took 3 of us 5mins to spot it. I suggest buying some in-depth HTML and CSS related books and downloading a modern browser like Chrome or Firefox that let you see the computed styles of any item at a glance, instead of trying random values in a script that shouldn't even be there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The last 5 elements have z-index:-60; set on them, if you change that to 0 they display normally. All the other elements have z-index of 0 as well.

Answer (score -2):

You are setting the z-index of the hidden `div`s to negative values, most likely due to this brilliant piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        var zIndexNumber = 1000;
        $('div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But hey I guess it's easier to blame a framework as widely used as jQuery instead of your poking around things you don't understand.

Edit: a `<li>` limitation? Seriously?

Comment: I was just brainstorming. I know jQuery is totally awsome... and unfortunately it's above my knowledge when it come to javascript. I'm sorry if this was a stupid question.

Comment: But hey I guess it's easier to be rude instead of empathetic.

Comment: @Rock - yours wasn't a stupid question. There's nothing wrong with asking if a bug happens to exist as you're exploring reasons why there's an error.